# Confusion about the notation of the event of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $X_n$ be a Markov-chain. What does the following event look like ?

$\{X_n=0 \text{ for some } n\geq 1\}$

Is it $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\{X_n=0\}$

or

is it $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\{X_n=0, X_{n-1} \neq 0,...,X_0\neq 0\}$?

Comment: Both unions are the same, are they not?

Comment: The sets in your second union are disjoint, but the result is the same. Still, I'd say your first union is the correct interpretation of the given expression.